# Do android textured point sprites work on software renderer?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I can successfully render non textured point sprites on both the emulator and multiple devices (2.1/2.2) but when I add textured code nothing is displayed on software rendered devices (or emulator) but fine on hardware accelerated devices. Is this a limitation of the software renderer or should I be able to have textured point sprites if I can get point sprites at all?

Thanks

Comment: Update: they only show the first pixel and stretch it to the desired point size.

Comment: Can anyone show they have it working on the emulator? Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the emulator does not support the GL_OES_point_sprite extension.

Comment: Hmm, Told by a customer that their device supports point sprites (my code tested for the above extension) yet they saw nothing. I had to revert back to quads (would prefer to use point sprites) in a hasty update.

Is there a sure fire method to test a device can texture point sprites? Is testing for that extension enough?

Comment: Right, I'm just scaling quads now to emulate point sprites. I zoom into my environment by changing field of view and divide the quad size by (max_fov / current_fov). It works.

Point sprites seem badly implemented to me..